# Piercing the Shadow Boundary with ViewEncapsulation.None on Host Element

Tags: css, angular

I have been messing with `ViewEncapsulation` and `::ng-deep` recently and ran into two separate issues which piqued my curiosity.

Suppose I have a component:

```
<div>
    <tooltip></tooltip>
</div>
```

From the outside, I can style elements inside of `tooltip` by doing something like:

`::ng-deep .tooltip-content {}`

Because `::ng-deep` is deprecated however, I began exploring alternatives. My first idea was to set `ViewEncapsulation.None` on the `tooltip` but then that would affect the rest of the front-end that used the `tooltip`. It wasn't a good option.

My second idea was to set `ViewEncapsulation.None` on the host element and then style the `tooltip` normally, without using `::ng-deep` but instead, appending `!important` to the required styles.

How does this work though? If the `tooltip` retains its `ViewEncapsulation`, how am I still able to pierce the shadow boundary?

Answer (score 0):

I use always `ViewEncapsulation.None` for reusable components. To avoid side-effect to rest of project, i use deep-nesting selector with name of component tag.

HTML:

```
<test-component>
   <div class="test">
      <tooltip></tooltip>
   </div>
</test-component>
```

scss:

```
test-component{
   .test { ... }
   tooltip { ... }
}
```

with that all `tooltip` tag in `test-component` ha unique style with out any side effect

Comment: The Angular team suggests [the opposite](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) (`::ng-deep` should be preferred to `/deep/`).

Comment: yes, you're right. i will update my answers to another solution.